# How to put date and time in a filename when doing a copy command?

Tags: file, datetime, vim, command-line, save

I want to make a backup of menu.vim using the copy command:

```
exe '!cp "c:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\menu.vim" d:\bkp_menu-vim_DATE_TIME.txt'
```

I would like to add the DATE and TIME to the name of the backup file.

I found this command: `<C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")`
but don't know how to insert it in the copy command. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to add the date/time to the name of the backup, or to the backup itself?

Comment: To the name of the backup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
:exe '!cp  c:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\menu.vim d:\bkp_menu-vim_'.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M").'.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks. Something goes wrong. Error message: `d:\\bkp_menu-vim_2012-12-03_13-12.txt` is not a directory. Shell returned 1. --> there is double `\\` after d:

Comment: That's weird. It might be a windows specific problem, as I don't get this on my linux.

Comment: I found the solution changing `!cp` in your code to the windows `!copy` command. Thanks. I would like to know also why it doesn't work with `!cp`.

Comment: I guess since `cp` is a unix command... And you're on a windows, right? Note that `!` executes a command on the system commandline. Type `:help !` in vim.

Answer (score 1):

Just type this as part of the command line when you get to the `_DATE` part; `<C-R>` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. When you enter the `=`, Vim will clear the command-line and lets you enter the expression, whose result is inserted when you press `<CR>` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>). See `:help c_CTRL-R` for details.

For such a simple way of backup, you may find my [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828) useful; it shortens this to just `:W` (when you have menu.vim open).

Comment: Thank you Ingo however, I don't want to insert date_time manually because I will insert the backup command in menu.vim self.